# Monolog : Large file loading issue

Tags: php, file, loading, monolog

I am using monolog with Symfony for displaying contenet.
I am facing issues when the file is large like more than 120 m.b or g.b then the server is stuck.
I have also added pagination but didn't succeed with load performance.
Can anyone suggest to me the option for reading the file and display its content in PHP.
I am using the file function for this.
Any help/hint more appreciates

Comment: Check your php ini for max upload size.

Comment: i have not uploaded any file then also need to check this?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Could it help to use a rotating log file, such that it does not grow endlessly?

Comment: i used the file function for reading content but still having issues,  i have generated only 1 log file. so Is the rotating log files useful?

Comment: "Useful" depends on your use case. Rotating the file daily or weekly could avoid that it grows too much

Comment: noted, let me R&D for this.